# How to stop GTest test-case execution, when first test failed

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm looking for some `#define` which can stop test-case execution if first test failed

```
TEST_F(TestInitializer, 1st-test) {
  Initiator.call();      
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_obj, onAction(false)).Times(AtLeast(0));

  // some define I want
  ::testing::stopIfFailed();
}

TEST_F(TestInitializer, 2nd-test) {
  // this test must not be executed if first test failed
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

run binary with flag `--gtest_break_on_failure`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the environment variable `GTEST_BREAK_ON_FAILURE` to something other than 0 and run the test.

Comment: please add a comment about why you don't like the answer

Comment: Sometimes you cannot influence the command line, but you _can_ control the environment.