# Prunning tests in Googletest

Tags: googletest

When there are two tests with an internal dependency, i.e. Have modules A and B where B uses A,

How can you avoid testing B when A has failed? (there's no point in such test)

Answer (score 1):

By design, the tests should not depend on each others execution, so there's no mechanism in GoogleTest that would allow you to define such dependency.

There's a possibility to just stop tests' execution at first failure, see [How to stop GTest test-case execution, when first test failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255739/how-to-stop-gtest-test-case-execution-when-first-test-failed)